# Get string value in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, hide, show

Here is my code for show and hide div using loop,i have 9 div like

```
<div ng-show="div1">.......</div>
<div ng-show="div2">.......</div>
<div ng-show="div3">.......</div>
<div ng-show="div4">.......</div>
<div ng-show="div5">.......</div>
<div ng-show="div6">.......</div>
<div ng-show="div7">.......</div>
<div ng-show="div8">.......</div>
<div ng-show="div9">.......</div>
```

am trying to show and hide the div using loop based on the value.suppose here am giving value as 4.i mean 4 div ll be show,

```
 var testOk='';
var testFAIL='';


$scope.tests=function(){    
for(var i=1; i<=9; i++){
    if(i <= 4)
    {
      testOk+='$scope.div'+i+'=true;';
    }
    else{
      testFAIL +='$scope.div'+i+'=false;';
    }       
}
 alert(testOk);
```

}

here testOK var contain showing div and testFail var contain hiding div,
output:-

```
testOK =$scope.Div1=true;$scope.Div2=true;$scope.Div3=true;$scope.Div4=true;
testFAIL =$scope.Div5=false;$scope.Div6=false;$scope.Div7=false;$scope.Div8=false;$scope.Div9=false;
```

how can i bind that value in div section.i hope u understand what am trying to asking.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want to print in dive? If you want to print only the no of divs(eg: value is having 4) then use ng-repeat in html directly.

Comment: i want to show and hide div,

Answer (score 1):

You have a weird approach for this. I'd show/hide divs like this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.nums = []
  for (var i=0; i <= 9; i++) {
    $scope.nums.push(i);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input ng-model="hideFrom" placeholder="Hide from this number onwards">
  <div ng-repeat="num in nums" ng-hide="hideFrom && $index >= hideFrom">
    {{num}}
  </div>
</div>
```